# Android Create GestureOverlay as a System Alert View (on top of all apps)

Tags: android, service, overlay, gesture, onfocus

I want to create a gestureoverlay for an app. I want the gesutureoverlay to be ontop of all other views. I have done this with a textbox and a button so far. I have the below code which creates the overlay on top of all apps but I can not use anything else in any others app or home screen. The app takes away from being able to focus in on the background view. I do however get my gesture overlay to work.

How do I at the very least get the phone to work normally but get to see the swipes the user makes (create a gesture overlay) on top of all apps?
 This is what I have so far

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM | 
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    GestureOverlayView g = new GestureOverlayView(getBaseContext());
    g.setGestureVisible(true);
    g.setEventsInterceptionEnabled(true);
    wm.addView(g, params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks because your code helped me to get my GestureOverlayView working on top.

I am working on something similar also and as far as I know you cant do this, at least just like that. To do that you need to have INJECT_PERSMISSION and this permission is grant only to system signed app, therefore you can´t do it using Android APIs if you dont have your ROM sign.

Of course there are other ways to do that.

What you might do is to get events in your activity and  "re-insert" them from your activity to the activity under you. And this is something you cant do through android.

Take a look [here](http://www.pocketmagic.net/2013/01/programmatically-injecting-events-on-android-part-2/#.USY3NKW6d6t) and [here](http://softteco.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/android-writing-events-low-level-touch.html).

In these links you can find further information about how to inject event into Android system.